# How to make Mathematica solve this simple DAE

Tags: differential-equations

When I try to solve the following DAE ("harmonic oscillator" + Coulomb friction)

$$
x''(t) + 10 x(t) + 0.2  l(t)  \operatorname{sign}(x'(t))=0 \\
y''(t) + 10 y(t) + 10 = l(t) \\
y(t) = 0
$$

using `NDSolve` as in

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 10 x[t] + 0.2 l[t] Sign[x'[t]] == 0, 
               y''[t] + 10 y[t] + 10 == l[t], 
               y[t] == 0, 
               x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {x, y, l}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I get a completely different (and wrong) result

[image]

than when I substitute $l(t) = 10$ (from the 2. and 3. equation) into the 1. equation

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 10 x[t] + 0.2 * 10 Sign[x'[t]]== 0, 
                x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which results in

[image]

and is of course also incorrect.

How can one solve this DAE?

Comment: Is the first code block above the same code you used to create the first plot?  When I try it, I get a "repeated convergence test failure" error.  (I'm using MM 12.3 on Mac OS.)

Comment: I actually used `\lambda` instead of `l`. I know this shouldn't make any difference but it seems it does because with `\lambda` it works, with `l` it doesn't. I'm on version 11.2.

sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 10 x[t] + 0.2 \[Lambda][t] Sign[x'[t]] == 0, 
   y''[t] + 10 y[t] + 10 == \[Lambda][t], y[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
   x'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {x, y, \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 10}]

Comment: I tried other letters from the greek alphabet as well. The code seems to run with all of them if you replace `l` by them. Does anyone else experience this weird behaviour on his/her machine?

Comment: OK, that's *got* to be a bug.  I will note, though, than in 12.3 I get a nice oscillatory solution once I replace `l` with `\[Lambda]`.  [Here's my results on Imgur.](https://imgur.com/a/XiGp8eQ)

Comment: Unfortunately still not the the result I would expect from this DAE...

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Can't reproduce it in 12.3.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved with DAE solver and special options

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 10 x[t] + 0.2 l[t] Sign[x'[t]] == 0, 
   y''[t] + 10 y[t] + 10 == l[t], y[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
   y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {x, y, l}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "IndexReduction" -> Automatic}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
  PrecisionGoal -> 7]

Plot[x[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]